# SelectList with MVC2 and custom ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, selectlist

I have created a custom ViewModel and one of the fields is a SelectList/DropDownlist. I wanted to use EditorForModel to display the ViewModel. All the fields work except the SelectList. I have tried a few different things and nothing has come up. I saw on one post that EditorForModel was not "smart enough" to do a DropDownList and I was wondering if that is true. The EditorForModel is so much easier to use and less typing :)

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I figured it out. What I ended up doing was using the UIHint("TemplateName") and in the EditorTemplates folder created a .ascx file that outputted was I expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your viewmodel, you should have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Months { get; set; }
```

And in the aspx, you need to bind it as follows:

```
<%
    var htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> { { "data-autopostback", "true" } }; 
%>

<%:Html.DropDownList("Month", Model.Months, "-- All --", htmlAttributes)%>
```

You need to ensure that you populate the Months property before passing it to the view.

Let me know if you need the code to populate the Months property.

Comment: I think you missed my point. I wanted to try and use the EditorForModel(), which means I would not have to use the Html.DropDownList. That is what I'm trying to figure is possible.

Comment: if you have IEnumerable<SelectListItem> in the ViewModel how are you going to get the selected value back ? cuz on the form post you get a string[] with the selected keys for this Property

Comment: Omu, the parameter should be named Month in the method used by the controller to get the selected value. I've not tested it for multi-select drop downs though.